# how to run 2 or more bash/unix scripts in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, unix, parallel-processing

So, I just wanted to know So, I just wanted to know how 2 or more scripts can be run in parallel. I searched a few places and saw mentions of using the '&' in between the various scripts I have but I would not be sure. So, can anyone provide me ideas how it can be possible or various ways I can initiate the process?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way :

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/my-process-1 --args1 &
/usr/bin/my-process-2 --args2 &
/usr/bin/my-process-3 --args3 &

wait
echo all processes complete
```

Source : https://www.codeword.xyz/2015/09/02/three-ways-to-script-processes-in-parallel/

Comment: So only using the & between the scripts is the way to do it? Thanks

Comment: It's the easiest way you got to do it, but you can check in the link for more ways to do it, if the & is a problem !

Answer (score 1):

Using & that put the application in the background.

from the man bash.

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

For example.

Running shell script with shell script you can do like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
sh ./script1 &
sh ./script2 &
```